# Libtorrent library

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

I am using the boost for my application when I tried building using VIsual studio 9.0 i get
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libtorrent.lib'

how to make the libtorrent.lib . I am having trouble in this ....if any one is having any solution please help me.

Comment: I presume you have to build something else first to create libtorrent.lib...

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with boost.

Comment: i followed steps given in the http://limewire.negatis.com/index.php?title=Visual_Studio_libtorrent  but still not getting

Comment: You already have one topic open.

Comment: ya ..I know that...but I am not able to solve this one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .lib is not included in your project. Make sure you are linking it in; Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies

Another altnerative is to simply copy the .lib to your project folder but don't, it's bound to create problems later on.

Sometimes the .lib is not shipped with the library, so you need to compile it yourself. The README will tell you this. If this is the case, they usually ship with a .sln file you can open and the just compile it into a .lib file which you then reference in your main application, as I wrote above

Comment: please tell me how to create the .lib file .

Comment: First of all; can you find the .sln file in your libtorrent folder?

Comment: no I dont have anything like that. I have only created the dll file for boost.